# Triangle Distribution, How to find Upper Bound ? if you have median and lower bound

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

if the lowerbound is 3 and Median is 9, How do I calculate the Upper Bound ?

I have been told x is drawn from a symmetric triangle distribution. Im not sure which value to use(I have to sub it into a formula) , I was thinking if perhaps I had the upper bound,lower bound and median. I could work out the mean and use the mean value ?

Comment: What on _earth_ does this have to do with the _normal_ distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint1: In a symmetric distribution the mean equals the median.

Hint2: Since the triangle distribution is symmetric, you can infer that $b-a=c-b$ according to the notation in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution), where $a$ is the lower bound and $b=$ median and mean value (due to symmetry).

Comment: thanks, what value do you suggest I use ? the lower bound or the mean value ?

Comment: @Amy2014 You need both to find $c$ which is the upper bound. Just plug in $a=3$ and $b=9$ in the above equation that I gave you in my answer